# Which Magento Soap V2 method should I use for external links?

Tags: api, magento, soap, magento-1.9

I am working on a script that imports all product information from a Magento 1.9.3.1 website.

I cant seem to find a method which allows me to get the `external links` data which is associated with every product.

(See screenshot)

[image]

Does anyone know which method I need to use?

A list of methods can be found here:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html#Introduction-APIMethods

I think I have used all catalog related methods but none of them seem to return the data I need.

Comment: see this http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-v2-soap-demystified/ it will helps to you

Comment: maybe it's help http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11091/get-correct-product-url-from-soap-api

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.update.html

From your screenshots, these look like custom attributes. Obtain their codes from Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes. Then, in the catalog_product.update call, include them in `additonal_attributes` as an array or arrays.

Example:
`'additional_attributes' => array(
    array('key' => 'ready_link', 'value'=> '...'),
    array('key' => 'itunes_link', 'value'=> '...'),
)`